# BigQuery Python API GET Tables

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to access my data using the BigQuery API Python Library but can't seem to do so. My code is below. The data that I used in the code was also used [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get#try-it) and it worked there but in my code throws a `TypeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` error.

If I just do a `print response` instead, output is `<googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest object at 0x1031d0d50>`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import logging
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
logging.basicConfig()
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
tables = bigquery_service.tables()
response= tables.get(projectId=project_id, datasetId=dataset_id, tableId=table_id)
print response['kind'] #causes TypeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Have you debugged the response object ? I think tables.get wont return the desired output

Comment: Try to add __unicode__ methods to your function

Comment: @Kalanamith I'm not too sure how one would go about debugging the response object? 
By adding unicode methods, do you mean, `unicode(project_id)` , `unicode(dataset_id)` etc ? If so, then I just tried that but to no avail :(

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/ this has indepth insights on debugging and its possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `.execute()` at the end of LN 8:

```
[..]
response= tables.get(projectId=project_id, datasetId=dataset_id, tableId=table_id).execute()
[..]
```